# possible to get textual ratings from the win phone 8 api?

Tags: windows-phone

is it possible to get the textual ratings from the windows phone 8 market via the api?
I know that I can get the apps in the market but don't know if the other thing is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can call to the MarketplaceDetail Launcher like [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394030%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) exposes.

Comment: There I can just show it but I need to have the data in my app